# How do I create bar charts in R where the starting point of the bar is greater than zero?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a series of bar charts (to be replicated for multiple sites) that highlight the difference between the main site and the satellite locations. I can come somewhat close using geom_point, but I'd like to have them represented as bar charts, where the bar starts at the lowest point, there are labels for the main site and satellite locations, as well as the difference between them. Here is some sample code and screenshots of what I have, and an idea of what I'd like it to look like.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

site <- c("Site A", "Main Site", "Site A", "Main Site", "Site A", "Main Site")
year <- c("2013", "2013", "2014", "2014","2015", "2015" )
value <- c(57, 74, 60, 50, 60, 68)

df <- data.frame (site, year, value)

df %>%
  mutate (label = paste0(site, " (", value, ")")) %>%
  ggplot (aes (x = year, y = value, group = site, colour = site)) +
  geom_point (size = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c (0,100)) +
  geom_text (aes(label = label))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Barcharts start at 0. But you can use `geom_rect` to draw rectangles wherever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on the comment from @gregor, you can try the below (note `dcast` is from `reshape2` and the heavy use of `dplyr`

```
df %>%
  dcast(year~site) %>%
  mutate(midpt = (`Main Site` + `Site A`)/2
         , dir = factor( (`Main Site` - `Site A`) > 0
                         , levels = c(FALSE,TRUE)
                         , labels = c("Negative", "Positive"))
         , diff = abs(`Main Site` - `Site A`)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year
             , y = midpt
             , fill = dir
             , height = diff)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Positive" = "darkgreen"
                               , "Negative" = "red3"))
```

[image]

If you have more than 2 sites, you would likely want a more flexible solution, probably using `dplyr` directly.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work exactly how I was hoping. The top and bottom of the chart should correspond to the data. I've managed a solution via brute force that I'm going to post.

Comment: Sorry about the earlier version -- I missed the step of re-calculating/adding the height. (Stupid mistake, but fixed now. Though not sure it is necessarily better than using `geom_rect`)

Comment: Thanks - I like how you set the factors based on positive/negative results. I'll use it.

Answer (score 1):

Using the comment from @Gregor I managed to come up with something that will work. Probably isn't the most elegant solution but will work for now.

```
df %>%
  spread(site, value) %>%
  mutate (diff = SiteA - MainSite) %>% 
  mutate (AboveBelow = recode (diff," -100:-1 = 'Below';
                               0 = 'No Difference';
                               1:100 = 'Above'")) %>%
  ggplot() +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Year", breaks = c (2013, 2014, 2015)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Percentage", limits = c(0,100)) + 
  geom_rect (aes (xmin = year - 0.33, xmax = year + 0.33, ymin = SiteA, ymax = MainSite, fill = AboveBelow)) +
  geom_text (aes (x = year, y = ifelse (diff < 0, MainSite + 5, MainSite - 3), label = paste0("MainSite - ", MainSite))) +
  geom_text (aes (x = year, y = ifelse (diff < 0, SiteA - 3, SiteA +5), label = paste0("SiteA - ", SiteA))) +
  geom_text (aes (x = year, y = MainSite + (diff/2), label = diff)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "red", "white" ))
```

Gives me this:

[image]